# SQL Query Date Sort Order Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, date

I am making a pivot table with dates across the top, customers down the side and sales data in the middle.  As part of that, I am getting my IN clause from a temporary table #FileDates.  Here is the code that works to get the dates in oldest to newest order.  I would like to get it in newest to oldest order.

```
SELECT * INTO #FileDates
FROM
    ( SELECT distinct DLDate [DATE] from Daily where DLDate between @begin31 and @end  )   TAB;
```

This is followed by:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106) + ']', 
           '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106) + ']')
           FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [DATE] FROM #FileDates ) PV
```

I've tried to put an order by clause in my subquery but it didn't work because you can't have order by in inline SQL.  I tried to rewrite it to:

```
SELECT distinct DLDate [DATE] into #FileDates 
from Daily where DLDate between @begin31 and @end  order by Date desc
```

And the command executed but the dates were not in the right order.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Ghost's suggestion and ordered it on the way out so my select code for my columns is now:

```
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106) + ']', 
       '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106) + ']')
       FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [DATE] FROM #FileDates ) PV   order by [DATE] desc
```

Comment: `@cols` is a scalar variable. It is unknown what value from multiple rows will be assigned to it. use `top 1` with `order by` to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an order if you have a TOP. I wouldn't think you'll have 10 million rows.

```
SELECT * INTO #FileDates
FROM (
   SELECT distinct TOP 999999999 DLDate [DATE]
   from Daily
   where DLDate between @begin31 and @end
   ORDER BY DLDate DESC
)   TAB;
```

But, here is how i'd write it if the temp table was explicitly declared.

```
INSERT INTO #FileDates
   SELECT distinct DLDate [DATE]
   from Daily
   where DLDate between @begin31 and @end
   ORDER BY DLDate DESC
```

Comment: Good thoughts but neither worked.  Asc and Desc gave me the same results --> Oldest to newest.

Comment: @Missy Keep in mind that just because data is inserted into a table in a certain order, that doesn't mean it will display that way when read back out. When you are selecting against #FileDates, you need to have that ordered by as well.

Comment: Okay -- I will check that out.   Thank you for your help, Ghost :)   Love the handle.